# writing datastream wirh defined delay between each byte

Tags: c, usb, delay, ftdi, writefile

I need to send a constant data stream from a computer to a device. The device is connected to a ftdi-chip and the ftdi is communicating via usb with the computer. Unfortunately, at full speed, the device needs a delay between each transferred byte.

Issue:

At present I’m using WriteFile() with a hand written Delay (this is just a sample, not the full code):

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)

{

    WriteFile( m_hIDComDev, (LPSTR) &ucByte, 1, &dwBytesWritten, &m_OverlappedWrite )

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);

    while (double(stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) < DELAY)
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    }
}
```

Depending on the mood of my machine, this delay differs between 100 us and nearly 1s. I use a Scope to display the delay at the ftdi output.

Question:

Is there a way to configure the com port or the ftdi with a defined delay between each byte?
With over words, getting rid of the “for” and use WriteFile with the size of the data instead of 1.

Alternatively, does anyone know a different way, which fits?

Limitation:

The whole Program should be time optimized. The device can run with 230,4kBaud. Running with lower speed (38,4kBaud) already solves the problem. However, the overall time is too long.

Programming in C using Visual Studio.

Comment: How long a delay? Could you just use two stop bits, assuming the virtual UART supports that? And that use of `double` as a function is not C, is it?

Comment: your right, it's cpp. the delay should be between 10us an 100 us

Comment: I'm allready using two stop bits ;) that fits a lower Speed, but not 230,4k

Comment: Lower the speed until the delay is no longer required.  Short delays such as you describe are 'unfriendly' to general-purpose desktop OS and cannot be reliably or efficiently generated by software:(   If you have to drop the speed so far, (eg, your 38k), that it's unacceptable for your requirements, then you are in trouble and you have an overall hardware design fail.

Comment: Normally we use flow control signals in order to delay UART Tx until the receiver is ready.

Comment: Martin, that is what I already did. 38,4kBaud is the limit. 

Turbo, actually I’m thinking about doing this. With a handshake, this looks more safe and easy. However, a change on hardware means a lot of work. Yet, I try to avoid this.